# How to Install .exe file as Azure Vm Extension?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to create a azure virtual machine extension.The extension is .exe file.Is there any custom Method/API  to install .exe file as VM extension?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can for example use VM Role or Start-up tasks. See here https://dzone.com/articles/options-installing-third-party and here http://wely-lau.net/2011/10/10/can-we-install-custom-software-on-windows-azure/